# How to get rank of products in marketwise in ssas

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

I have dimension hierarchy like Market-->group1-->group2-->product.
I want rank of Group2 members for particular Market on basis of a measure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following `mdx` function:

[Rank](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144726.aspx)  : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144726.aspx